# Collect and display separately the values of dynamic editTexts in second activity

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I created three Edit Text inputs and another set of inputs that should be added dynamically when you click on Add more button.

I want to collect the data submitted from the second activity and separating them according to how many times the add more button is clicked

My problem is when I click on the Submit button I can get the initial values of the static edit Text field in the second activity but I can't get the values of the dynamic edit Text.

I will appreciate any assistance offered
Thanks

The XML layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="480dp"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="422dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/title_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter product Title"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/product_name_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Product Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/product_number_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Product Number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="#555"
                android:onClick="onAddField"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Add Field"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
                android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="#555"
                android:onClick="onAddField"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Add Field"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The dynamic Layout

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="New Field"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="26dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter product Title"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Product Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Product Number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:onClick="onDelete" />
```

The Activity.java
The add More button

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
    dynamicEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();//added this

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    // Add the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() 
- 1);

    EditText dynamicText = new EditText(this);//added this
   // EditText dynamicText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_layout);
    dynamicEditTexts.add(dynamicText);

}
```

The Submit Button

```
public void getValue(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Output.class);
    titleM = findViewById(R.id.title_main);
    productNameM = findViewById(R.id.product_name_main);
    productNumberM = findViewById(R.id.product_number_main);

    //getting the texts
    String Title = titleM.getText().toString();
    String PName = productNameM.getText().toString();
    double PNumber = 
    Double.parseDouble(productNumberM.getText().toString());

    // ******** FOR THE DYNAMIC EDITEXT FIELDS ************
    String[] inputItems = new String[dynamicEditTexts.size()];
    String string = String.valueOf(dynamicEditTexts.size());
    for(int j = 0; j <dynamicEditTexts.size(); j++){
        inputItems[j] = dynamicEditTexts.get(j).getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("dynamicData", inputItems[j]);
  }

    intent.putExtra("title", Title);
    intent.putExtra("pname", PName);
    intent.putExtra("pnumber", PNumber);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }
```

The Output.class

```
//GETTING ITEMS FROM THE MAIN ACTIVITY
    //for the static texts
    String StaticProductTitle = 
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    String StaticProductName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pname");
    double StaticProductNumber = 
    getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("pnumber");

    //getting for the dynamic results
    Intent collectDynamicData = getIntent();

    ArrayList<String>alldynamicTexts = (ArrayList<String>) 
    collectDynamicData.getSerializableExtra("dynamicData");




        //FORMATING THE NUMBERS TO DISPLAY IN A NUMBER PATTERN
        DecimalFormat formate = new DecimalFormat();//"#,###,###"
        String FormateStaticNumber;
        String FormateDynamicNumber;
        FormateStaticNumber = formate.format(StaticProductNumber);
        FormateDynamicNumber = formate.format(alldynamicTexts);

        //Setting the Results to the Static OutPut
        StaticTitle.setText(StaticProductTitle);
        StaticPName.setText(StaticProductName);
        StaticPNumber.setText(FormateStaticNumber);

        //Setting the Result of The Dynamic Outputs
        DynamicPTitle.setText(FormateDynamicNumber);
        //DynamicPTitle.setText((CharSequence) alldynamicTexts);
        //DynamicPTitle.setText(array);
        //DynamicPName.setText(DynamicProductName);
        //DynamicPNumber.setText(FormateDynamicNumber);

}
```

UPDATE ON THE OUTPUT

```
Intent collectDynamicData = getIntent();
    String[] dynamicItems = collectDynamicData.getStringArrayExtra("dynamicData");
    ArrayList<String> alldynamicTexts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dynamicItems));
    String newText = (String.valueOf(alldynamicTexts));
    DynamicPTitle.setText(newText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the previous value you put in your intent extras when collecting your dynamic edittext field values in `getValue` method.

What you need to do is collect all strings in a list, array or a similar data structure and put them once in the extras. So to achieve that you should rewrite your `for` logic as below:

```
for (int j = 0; j <dynamicEditTexts.size(); j++) {
    inputItems[j] = dynamicEditTexts.get(j).getText().toString();
}
intent.putExtra("dynamicData", inputItems);
```

Since you are injecting your data as a string array you must also read it back as a string array, so your Output.java would look like:

```
String[] dynamicItems = collectDynamicData.getStringArrayExtra("dynamicData");
```

And to convert it into an string list:

```
ArrayList<String> alldynamicTexts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dynamicItems));
```

Of course you can inject them as a string array list in the first place and read them back using `collectDynamicData.getStringArrayListExtra("dynamicData")`, choose whatever methods that suits you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I'm trying it now, but what about the Output.java. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jblaq you're welcome and sorry for the delay, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, sir. Sorry I wasn't online. I'll do as you've said and tell you the result. Thanks once again...

Comment: But considering that I am collecting both String and Integer values, is that still applicable? Thanks again

Comment: I've tried it and I got this error-- "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList"

Comment: Since what you're collecting from edit text is string you would need to cal `Integer.parseInt()` at some point. If you are aware the type of data for each edit text you're collecting, you can parse it right away and pass the values as a custom parcelable object among other string values or an integer array. But if not you can try to parse them after retrieving them.

Comment: Wrap it in a `new ArrayList<>()`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your suggestions, and I got something like this " [] " as the output. I know I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out. Please kindly check my updated code above for more clarity. I tried that for testing purposes, I would like to get all the dynamic inputs and separate them before displaying them.  I'm so sorry for the inconveniences. Thanks again.

Comment: Since you ARE getting an output not a null value, shows that you're doing the parcelable data transfer right; Your updated output also seems right. I suspect your for clause in `getValue` method does not get called at all hence no data entry. You can either debug your code using Android Studio debugging tool or make sure of what extras you're actually pushing into intent and receive as well.